# Why does FastApi produce and error with subsequent routes

Tags: python, routes, fastapi

I am running fastAPI on wsl2 and I have noticed only the root route is working. Subsequent routes generate a `{"detail":"Not Found"}` not sure the origin of the error

```py
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI


app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}

@app.get("/home")
async def read_home():
    return {"message": "Welcome to the home page!"}

@app.get("/services")
async def read_services():
    return {"message": "Check out our services here!"}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)
```

Curl outputs the following

```bash
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8000
{"message": "Hello World"}
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/home
{"detail":"Not Found"}
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/services
{"detail":"Not Found"}
```

I am using
`Python 3.10.12`
`uvicorn==0.27.0`
`fastapi==0.109.0`

Also not the routes are not showing up in docs
[image]

Comment: You're running a different script / the application hasn't been restarted since you changed your routes; stop the application, confirm that if you make a request you get an error back (i.e. unable to connect to the server) and restart it.

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks....took me ages to solve this one